# Why is this D code slower than a similar C# implementation?

Tags: performance, d

I was playing around D and ported a sample project I've written in C# to test how it performs. I won't lie saying that I wasn't suprised seeing D was much slower than C# because that was my first attempt to write something in D.

In short, C# executes the code in 32 seconds, while D requires 54 seconds. The code is a bit large for a snippet, but if anyone can provide a little bit of time to explain why this happened/what's wrong with my D code would be great.

Here's a short piece of my code:

```
void ProcessReel(int reelIndex, string pattern, Game game)
{
    counter++;
    if(reelIndex == game.Reels.length) 
    {
        Symbol winningSymbol;
        auto patternLength = 0;


        auto p3_1 = pattern[0..3];
        auto p3_2 = pattern[2..5];
        auto p4_1 = pattern[0..4];
        auto p4_2 = pattern[1..5];

        auto pos = GetFromDict(p3_1, p3_2, game);
        if(pos != null)
        {
            winningSymbol = pos._Symbol;
            patternLength = pos.PatternLength;
        }

        pos = GetFromDict(p4_1, p4_2, game);
        if(pos != null)
        {
            winningSymbol = pos._Symbol;
            patternLength = pos.PatternLength;
        }

        if(pattern in patternTable)
        {
            auto combination = patternTable[pattern];
            winningSymbol = combination._Symbol;
            patternLength = combination.PatternLength;
        }

        if(winningSymbol !is null)
        {
            winningSymbol.Combinations++;
        }
        return;
    }

    auto reel = game.Reels[reelIndex];
    for(int i = 0; i < reel.ReelStrip.length; i++)
    {
        auto p = pattern;
        auto sym = reel.ReelStrip[i];
        p ~= std.conv.to!string(sym);
        ProcessReel(reelIndex + 1, p, game);
    }
}
```

Full code can be downloaded from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3055964/D.tar.gz)

I'm compiling with the following compiler arguments

```
dmd Test.d -O -release -inline -boundscheck=off
```

Thanks.

UPDATE

Here's C# code. It was supposed to run in parallel, that's why it has a lock inside, but I made it serial for a bit fair competition, however, even with this lock in place, C# beats D.

```
public static void ProcessReel(int reelIndex, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<byte, WinPossibility>> dict, string pattern, AnalyzedResult result)
{
    if (reelIndex == result.Game.ReelCollection[0].Reels.Count)  // This is the last reel. Time to analyze those shit :((
    {
        Symbol winningSymbol = null;
        var patternLength = 0;

        var p3_1 = pattern.Substring(0, 3);
        var p3_2 = pattern.Substring(2, 3);
        var p4_1 = pattern.Substring(0, 4);
        var p4_2 = pattern.Substring(1, 4);

        if (result.PatternTable.ContainsKey(p3_1) || result.PatternTable.ContainsKey(p3_2))
        {
            var winCombination = Helper.GetFromDict(p3_1, p3_2, result);
            var symbol = winCombination.Symbol;
            winningSymbol = symbol;
            patternLength = winCombination.PatternLength;
        }

        if (result.PatternTable.ContainsKey(p4_1) || result.PatternTable.ContainsKey(p4_2))
        {
            var winCombination = Helper.GetFromDict(p4_1, p4_2, result);
            var symbol = winCombination.Symbol;
            winningSymbol = symbol;
            patternLength = winCombination.PatternLength;
        }

        if (result.PatternTable.ContainsKey(pattern))
        {
            var winCombination = result.PatternTable[pattern];
            var symbol = winCombination.Symbol;
            winningSymbol = symbol;
            patternLength = winCombination.PatternLength;
        }

        if (winningSymbol != null)
        {
            lock (dict)
            {
                var d = dict[patternLength];
                if (d.ContainsKey(winningSymbol.Code))
                    d[winningSymbol.Code].Combinations += 1;
                else
                    d.Add(winningSymbol.Code, new WinPossibility(winningSymbol, patternLength, 1));
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    var reel = result.Game.ReelCollection[0].Reels[reelIndex];

    //if (reelIndex == 0)
    //{
    //    Parallel.For(0, reel.ReelStrip.Length, r1 =>
    //    {
    //        var p = pattern;
    //        var sym = reel.ReelStrip[r1];
    //        p += sym;

    //        ProcessReel(reelIndex + 1, dict, p, result);
    //    });
    //}
    //else
    //{
        for (int r1 = 0; r1 < reel.ReelStrip.Length; r1++)
        {
            var p = pattern;
            var sym = reel.ReelStrip[r1];
            p += sym;

            ProcessReel(reelIndex + 1, dict, p, result);
        }
    //}
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I just downloaded GDCC 4.9. It helped, calculation time is now down to 38 seconds from 54, but still inferior to .NET/C#...

Comment: I don’t see any C#. (If it’s in your link, please include it here.)

Comment: Perhaps a question for [Stack Exchange Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Use a profiler on each one, find out what functions/operations are performing significantly different.  Quite possibly it is data dependent.

Comment: Are the edges of p3_2 and p4_2 supposed to be different in D than in C#? And what does GetFromDict look like in D?

Comment: "It helped, calculation time is now down to 38 seconds from 54, but still inferior to .NET/C#..." but "C# executes the code in 32 seconds". Not much of a difference, really. Modern JIT VMs often don't get enough credit - was/is it expected for the D to be [much] faster?

Comment: (I'm not saying that D [shouldn't be faster](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/xjvlpegvhcwioqrjhzsn@forum.dlang.org#post-xjvlpegvhcwioqrjhzsn:40forum.dlang.org), but it's nice to clarify expectations.)

Comment: Well, I expected 10%-20% improvement depending on use case scenario...

Comment: @Davita One way that may help isolate the cause is to see if the benchmark shows algorithmic complexity differences. Also do make that they operate on the same data and produce the same [correct] results.

Comment: A simple thing: try with  `Symbol[] Symbols` and  `Reel[] Reels` instead of *std.array.Array* and replace `insert()` by `~=`. The run-time is reduced by 15% like this, from my side (win32, dmd 2.066.1). Maybe even faster if you use an std.array.Appender.

Comment: Thanks, but the time it takes to populate arrays is not included in the test. Only the time of recursion function is taken in account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a few things which makes D version slower.

1.)

```
if(pattern in patternTable) {
    auto combination = patternTable[pattern];
```

You make 2 lookups here instead of one, you should use this:

```
auto combination = pattern in patternTable;
if(combination) {
    ...
```

Same for GetFromDict function

2.)
array concatenation is slow it is better to use std.array.Appender

3.)
there is no need to use std.container.Array, you could use standart D arrays with appender

4.) to!string(sym) is slow, you colud improve speed for sym in range 0 .. 10 with:

```
cast(char)('0' + sym)
```

5.)
DMD is slow you should try ldc and gdc with appropeiate flags for eg.:

```
gdc -O3 -finline -fno-bounds-check  -frelease
```

With some changes I was able to make it many times faster from almost 50s to 15s

here is my code:
[modified code](http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/b2c8db08973f)

**UPDATE**

I have some mistakes here is another version which is little slower but should give right results:

http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/cd6a7af786ec

Comment: Unbelievable, D is really efficient. I didn't expect twice as much performance compared to CLR. Thanks Kozzi :)

Comment: I have some errors is doesnt work as expected: here is better version is little slowe but accurate: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/cd6a7af786ec

Comment: Yes I noticed too, but unable to correct :). On my pc, it takes ~2 seconds more to complete, still much faster then CLR. One thing I don't understand, what role does "0" play in this code sym == "" ? pattern ~ "0": pattern ~ sym ? Thanks again :)

Comment: Because I change from int[] to string[], when code take reel.ReelStrip[i] which hase not value in case of int[] it returns 0 but in case of string[] it returns ""(empty string), so when "" occured "0" is used instead